# finding points along a vector in 3d

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have two points in 3d space, and i want to get a list of points between them which are located with "r" distance from each other. How can I do it most easily using the unity functions? 
[image]

Comment: this is precisely what **Lerp** is.  All you've done is describe the Lerp command.  A point between a and b is just Lerp(a,b, .5f) ... that one is half way between.  If you want ten steps it's just Lerp(a,b, .1f), Lerp(a,b, .2f), Lerp(a,b, .3f) and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Vector3[] GetPointsInbetween(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float offset){
    int count = (int)((b - a).magnitude / offset);
    Vector3[] result = new Vector3[count];

    Vector3 delta = (b - a).normalized * offset;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result[i] = a + delta * i;
        Debug.Log(result[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

but `.magnitude` and `.normalized` are very expensive operations, try to avoid using this in `Update()`

Comment: Despite being right, you should maybe skip the first i iteration (i = 0) since it is just the initial position.

Comment: What you've done here is re-write Lerp!  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Comment: lol it's funny I've never used Lerp for anything but smoothing out the movement :D I had forgotten Lerp is linear interpolation, good one @JoeBlow

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it by using `Vector3.MoveTowards` http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

Comment: Not really, what you want is Lerp.  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html  MoveTowards is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Unitiy functions, but formally you describe linear interpolation between the two points. The line segment between the points `A` and `B` can be described by the parameterized form

```
A * s + B * (1-s)
```

where `s` is from the interval `[0,1]`.

Comment: It's built-in to Unity - you use it in pretty much every other line of code! http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html